# Why is my StreamBuilder not updating my Post model?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have build my streambuilder successfully,it takes the value first time but when i update my content (post a new thing or patch) it does not update inside Streambuilder.Why?

```
Stream<List<Post>> FetchPostsStream(http.Client client) async* {
  List<Post> posts;
  final response = await http.get("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/?format=json");
  final parsed = jsonDecode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  posts = parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromJSON(json)).toList();
}

Stream fetchPostsStreaminit;

@override
void initState() {
    fetchPostsStreaminit = FetchPostsStream(http.Client());
  }


StreamBuilder<List<Post>>(
          stream: fetchPostsStreaminit,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

            return snapshot.hasData ?
           PostsList(posts:snapshot.data)   :   Text('Waiting');

          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how http works, http is one directional (you ask the server and get response). There is no way to workaround this with Stream you have to use sockets on the server, [HTTP/2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html) or any other solution so you can implement two directional communication (server give you data without explicit request).

Comment: Oh,thats why i am not getting updates then. I will work on websockets then.Thanks a lot!